# How do I get first child (td) with attribute?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to style the first table row with my attribute, but I can't figure it out.

Please take a look at the code - any idea why the "blue" rows aren't blue?

Thanks.

```css
#myTable tr[data-somedata] > td {
  background-color: red;
}

#myTable tr[data-somedata] > td ~ #myTable tr[data-somedata] > td {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>This should be normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This should be normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're not using the general sibling combinator `~` properly

Answer (score 1):

This is because your selector will work for `td` siblings, but `td` here are not sibling, sibling are `tr`. So you'll have to fix your selector to work with sibling `tr` then apply descendant or child selector.

```css
#myTable tr[data-somedata] > td {
  background-color: red;
}

#myTable tr[data-somedata] ~ tr[data-somedata] > td {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>This should be normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This should be normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken the path to follow in your selector.
tr are sibbling, you need to select each next ones : `tr ~tr` .

```css
#myTable tr[data-somedata] > td {
  background-color: red;
}

#myTable tr[data-somedata]   ~   tr[data-somedata] > td {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>This should be normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This should be normal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-somedata>
    <td>This should be blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

your selector

```
#myTable tr[data-somedata] > td ~ #myTable tr[data-somedata] > td
```

is looking for a td inside a tr with attribute data-somedata child of  table(#myTable) WICH stands inside  a td following another td that is standing in a tr with the attribute data-somedata itself child of #myTable  ... a bit too much here :)